# Chartjs multiple barcharts corresponding to one label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a question regarding barcharts in Chartjs.

I want to display multiple barcharts for each label, but it has proven very hard for some reason.

I am building a chart to display the amount of repetitions and sets someone has done, as a function of the date.

So on the X-axis I have the dates - and on the Y-axis I have the amount of repetitions. If the person has done 3 sets that day, it should display 3 bars on that date, where the value (height of the bar) is the number of repetitions.

For testing purposes I have three dates and a few sets/reps for each date:

`"2017-05-25"
- Set 1: 7 reps
"2017-05-30"
- Set 1: 8 reps
- Set 2: 9 reps
- Set 3: 10 reps
"2017-05-31"
- Set 1: 3 reps
- Set 2: 7 reps
- Set 3: 12 reps
- Set 4: 8 reps`

This is my current chartData object.

```
var chartData = {
      labels: Object.keys(items.dates),
      datasets: [{
           label: "Reps",
           backgroundColor: "blue",
           data: [7]
      }, {
           label: "Reps",
           backgroundColor: "red",
           data: [8, 9, 10]
      }, {
           label: "Reps",
           backgroundColor: "green",
           data: [3, 7, 12, 8]
      }]
};
```

The dates are displayed correctly, but I can't seem to get the reps/sets right. I believe I somehow have to group them some other way around or something.

All help appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Made a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ytkqwL9x/1/

As you can see, the sets fall into the wrong dates - in the first date: 2017-05-25, there is supposed to be only 1 set, but it shows 3 (7,8,3).

Comment: Sure! will do now, 2 sec

Comment: Check updated question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to arrange the `data` arrays of your datasets like this ...

```
var chartData = {
   labels: Object.keys(items.dates),
   datasets: [{
      label: "Reps",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      data: [7, 8, 3]
   }, {
      label: "Reps",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      data: [0, 9, 7]
   }, {
      label: "Reps",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      data: [0, 10, 12]
   }]
};
```

***note:*** if there is no data for a particular label (date) then you'd have to add a `0` for that

Here is the **[working example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2e0mmsq/)**

Comment: Haha that is so obvious now! Thanks a lot ! :)